# How to change colors of a Sharepoint list which is embedded in a section of a Sharepoint website

Tags: list, sharepoint, formatting

I managed to format my Sharepoint list so that every second row is colored in the theme color. As soon as I embed the list as a section on a Sharepoint website the color is gone. How do I fix this?! I'm clueless. Any tips are highly appreciated.

{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(@rowIndex%2==0,'ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt','')"
}

Answer (score 0):

It's a known case https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/issues/15, one workaround is using 'Embed' webpart instead of List webpart.